# Ms access always ask for a value

Tags: ms-access

The values are given and calculated and there are Qout and PctWaste before this expression

```
Expr4: Round([Qout]*[PctWaste]/100,2)
```

Still i am getting error , I am using access 2010. Any Help?

Qout : Expr2: [StockDataBank]![Qty]*[Forms]![WipFinMaster]![WipFinDetail1].[Form]![Total]

PctWaste : Expr3: GetPctWaste([RCode])

Its promopting for Qout and PctWaste while its value are already calculated.

Table StockDatabank : FSCode, RCode, Qty

Comment: Please post your query that you are using as well as your table structure.  Are you certain that you have the correct column names?  If you are defining these aliases in your query, then you have to either reuse the expressions or use a subquery.

Comment: Yes, the same name are in database too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the details that you have provided it sounds like you are trying to reuse column aliases in another column.

You cannot do that, you need to either reuse the expression or place the columns within a subquery.

Subquery:

```
select Round([Qout]*[PctWaste]/100,2)
from 
(
  select [StockDataBank]![Qty]*[Forms]![WipFinMaster]![WipFinDetail1].[Form]![Total] as Qout,
    GetPctWaste([RCode]) as PctWaste
  from yourtable
) src
```

Reuse the expressions:

```
select [StockDataBank]![Qty]*[Forms]![WipFinMaster]![WipFinDetail1].[Form]![Total] as Qout,
    GetPctWaste([RCode]) as PctWaste,
    Round([StockDataBank]![Qty]*[Forms]![WipFinMaster]![WipFinDetail1].[Form]![Total]*GetPctWaste([RCode])/100,2)
from yourtable
```

Comment: @WajahatKareem See my edit, I left off the alias for the subquery